# Template Arguments Needed in Return Types during Method Definition

Tags: c++, templates

Does anyone know why template arguments are needed for return-types but not for argument-types when defining template-methods?  An example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Car {
  Car drive(Car);  // will be defined after the template declaration.
};

// Attempt #1: does not compile.
// Error: use of class template Car requires template arguments
template<typename T>
inline Car Car<T>::drive(Car) {}

// Attempt #2: compiles!  
// The only difference is the use of template argument in return type.
// However, note that the argument to func does not require template argument!
template<typename T>
inline Car<T> Car<T>::drive(Car) {}
```

Not sure why the template argument is needed for the return-type but not required for the argument-type.  When Attempt #1 failed, I was expecting Attempt #2 to fail too and expected I would need:

```
template<typename T>
inline Car<T> Car<T>::drive(Car<T>) {}  // but no need to go this far.
```

but Attempt #2 worked!

Is there good reason for this behavior?

Comment: I think this is due to parsing from left to right:  After `template typename T>` we don't know what the template type is yet.  At `inline Car` we could still be declaring any kind of function, so `Car` isn't valid and you must clarify `Car<T>`.  After `Car<T>::...` you are now within the context of `struct Car<T>` and the argument `Car` is implicitly `Car<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because argument(s) type(s) of a method are deduced using class scope, but return type is deduced from the same scope where a class is defined if those methods are defined outside class scope. This is true for everything, not only templates. To add to your example, the following won't compile:

```
class Foo
{
    typedef int Bar;

    Bar foo () const;
};

Bar
Foo::foo () const
{
    return 0;
}
```

... and to fix it you have to tell exactly that Bar is from Foo's scope:

```
Foo::Bar
Foo::foo () const
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the rule.  I had suspected that the return-type is treated under a different scope as the argument-type too, but I can't understand the rationale behind it.  Why not have the parser treat the return-type within the scope of the argument-type also?

Answer (score 9):

First, you acknowledge this makes no sense: `Car c;`, right? `Car` must have template arguments. That's why you need to specify it on the return type, and on the class name.

But after the scope-resolution operator (`::`), `Car<T>` is *injected* as `Car`*, so `Car` is an alias to `Car<T>`. But this only happens inside the scope of `Car<T>`, which is why you need it everywhere else but not after `::`. Of course, you are free to explicitly specify the arguments yourself anyway.

---

*This feature is better explained like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    // as if the compiler did this:
    typedef foo<T> foo; // (of course, actually illegal)
};
```

`foo` is available within the scope of `foo<T>` as `foo<T>`. After the scope-resolution operator, though, that scope is available for use, and the template arguments are optional.

Comment: I'd vote you up since you independently said the same thing I did in a comment, but then if I were so confident that this was the right answer I would have just answered myself.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From N3225, 3.4.1/8 (unqualified name lookup), a name used after a member function's declarator-id shall be looked-up inside the class definition first.

> A name used in the definition of a
> member function (9.3) of class X
> following the function’s declarator-id
> (That is, an unqualified name that occurs, for instance, in a type or default argument expression in the parameter declaration-
> clause or in the function body.) or in the
> brace-or-equal-initializer of a
> non-static data member (9.2) of class
> X shall be declared in one of the
> following ways:
>
> — before its use in class X or be a
> member of a base class of X (10.2), or
>
> — if X is a nested class of class Y
> (9.7), before the definition of X in
> Y, or shall be a member of a base
> class of Y (this lookup applies in
> turn to Y ’s enclosing classes,
> starting with the innermost enclosing
> class), or
>
> — if X is a local class
> (9.8) or is a nested class of a local
> class, before the definition of class
> X in a block enclosing the definition
> of class X, or
>
> — if X is a member of
> namespace N, or is a nested class of a
> class that is a member of N, or is a
> local class or a nested class within a
> local class of a function that is a
> member of N, before the definition of
> class X in namespace N or in one of N
> ’s enclosing namespaces.

Then injected-class-name is a normal class member for the purpose of name lookup, and injected-class-name is declared at the beginning of the class, before any other members.

3.3.2/7

> The point of declaration for an
> injected-class-name (Clause 9) is
> immediately following the opening
> brace of the class definition.

3.4/3

> The injected-class-name of a class
> (Clause 9) is also considered to be a
> member of that class for the purposes
> of name hiding and lookup.

Lastly, for template,

14.6.1/3

> The injected-class-name of a class
> template or class template
> specialization can be used either with
> or without a template-argument-list
> wherever it is in scope.

Therefore,

```
template<typename T>
inline Car<T> Car<T>::drive(Car) {}
```

The first return type name Car cannot find injected-class-name, because it is looked up as a normal name and will find the global class Car.

But the second parameter type Car can find injected-class-name, because it is after the function's delcarator-id. Injected-class-name can be used with or without bracket T bracket.

So you got the answer now.

Comment: But this seems like a matter of the layout of C++ syntax and not of the semantic.  Had C++ decided to declare the return-type after the argument, as in `inline Car<T>::drive(x Car) Car<T> {}` like in the language `Go`, then both parameter types would appear after the declarator-id.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For C++0x, if you write like

`auto Car<T>::drive(Car)->Car { }`  You don't need that `<T>` because the trailing return type is after the function's declarator-id and thus looked up as injected-class-name